# C++ DLL in C# WinMobile 6.1 Project - 1c2 machine (Thumb) vs 14c machine (x86)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, windows-mobile

I am trying to import a few DLLs that have been compiled for 1c2 machine (thumb) into a WinMobile 6.1 C# Smart Device project.

However when i try to import them to my C# project I get "A reference to ... cannot be added", I can add DLLs that have been compiled for 14C machine (x86), my C# WinMobile project has Any CPU as it's setting, is it possible to import 1C2 machine DLLs or do I need these to be recompiled to 14C machine x86?

[image: DLL Import]

Comment: You can only reference a .NET assembly for everything else you have to import the reference. You need to explain what `1c2` and `14c` machines are exactly.

Comment: I am trying to import them, they are used internally to access device stuff like bluetooth USb, etc... It is explained 1c2 machine is (Thumb) for ARM CPUs in this case PXA270M and 14C machine is (x86) for x86 CPUs

Comment: So post the code you are using because the error you mention doesn't match what you claim you are doing.

Comment: ?? I am simply trying to right click the project and trying to add a reference to a DLL, nothing more, this is not at compile time or run time. VS simply does not let me add these DLLs

Comment: You only exlained the difference after you modified your question.  So post the code you are using.  If you are trying to drag and drop the dll as a reference thats only for .NET reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're trying to do.  You can't just "add a reference" to a native DLL from managed code.  "Add Reference" is specifically for adding managed references.

If you want to call your native DLL from managed code, you must write and call P/Invoke interop functions.  Even then, you can only call publicly exported C functions (not C++, unless it has a COM interface), so you may also have to write C stubs, or some form of factory functions to proxy any C++ calls you wish to make.

Comment: My program only calls one function, all the other DLLs reference themselves to access a bunch of libraries for NFC, Bluetooth, etc... Do I need to add them to the project or should I copy them to the directory? These are C libraries supplied by an external provider.

Comment: They need to be loadable, so either put them in your app folder or the `\Windows` folder.  They don't need to be in the project at all.

Comment: @AdamSurfari - The best way would be to create a wrapper class for the C dll.